# LoadControl causes a Parser Error

Tags: asp.net

We're using LoadControl to load an ascx file into a placeholder control dynamically. The codebehind looks very simple:

```
child = base.LoadControl(manufacturerTemplate.TemplatePath);
this.ManufacturerPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(child);
```

The control header looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyNamespace.MyControl" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" %>
```

I've verified spelling of everything and compilation. It works fine in the ASP.NET Development web server. But when I upload it to our IIS host, I recieve this error:

> Parser Error: Could not load type 'MyNamespace.MyControl.

The codebehind compiles without errors. It's actually a duplication of another control's codebehind. (verified that the spelling is accurate) One of the things I've tried is to modify the @Control directive to point to the 2nd control's codebehind (sharing the same functionality)....it works perfectly.

Some of the other things I've tried:

- File System Permissions
- Restarting IIS
- Clearing the ASP.NET Temp folder

So at this point, I've no idea why I can't use the codebehind that I'm attempting to add will not work. I can point it to the other class's codebehind, and it works fine. (after changing the "inherits" value) So I can only suppose that it is a compilation problem. But it builds correctly without errors.

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The project was a "Web Application" instead of a "Web Site. So it had to not only be compiled, but I had to deploy the website's assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Change your control tag to this

```
 <%@ Control ClassName="MyControl" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyControl" %>
```

On the ASPX page that you're using the control on, add this code

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/path/to/control/MyControl.ascx" %>
```

In your code behind use this

```
MyControl controlObject= (MyControl)LoadControl("~/path/to/control/MyControl.ascx");
this.Controls.Add(controlObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- Ensure that you fully clean and rebuild your application.
- Ensure that when you publish you application you delete (not replace!) all existing files.
- Ensure that if the control is in a subfolder or directory that it is referenced from that directory.
- Ensure that the dll for the ascx is in the bin folder.